# Java IOException, file path strangeness

Tags: java

I'm getting the 
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
and I can't see why.

If I try my code directly with a string, it works (folder exists, permissions ok, etc.)
When I try to build the string from an array, it fails with the exception above.
Here's the code, with commented lines that I've tried that fail and what works as well as what the println output is:

```
            // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Create a file chooser and select a directory
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

            int rVal = fc.showOpenDialog(MyApp.this);

            if (rVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                dlDirectory = fc.getSelectedFile().toString() + "\\"; 
                System.out.println("Selected Directory: " + dlDirectory);
            } else {
                System.out.println("No Selection");
            }

            ...
            ...(I create a string array of file names here)
            ...

            for (int i = 0; i < filesToRetrieve.length; i++) {

                    //put together the directory and file name
                    String dlFileName = (dlDirectory + filesToRetrieve[i]); 
                    try {   
                                System.out.println(dlDirectory); // output: C:\Users\michael\Documents\tmp\ (as expected)
                                System.out.println(filesToRetrieve[i]); // output: nameoffile.txt (as expected)
                                System.out.println(dlFileName); // output: C:\Users\michael\Documents\tmp\nameoffile.txt (as expected)

                                File myFile = new File(dlFileName); //<--this does not work -- java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
                                //File myFile = new File(dlDirectory + filesToRetrieve[i]); //<--this does not work either

                                //File myFile = new File(dlDirectory + "nameoffile.txt");  // <--this does work !?!?

                                if(!myFile.exists()) {
                                    System.out.println("file does not exist");
                                    myFile.createNewFile();
                                } 
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err
                                .println("failed");
                        System.err.println(e);
                    }       
            }
```

Can anyone see why this is happening?
Thanks.

Comment: Should not you use \\ between directory and filesToRetrieve instead of single \?

Comment: You should use `\\\` instead of this `\\`

Comment: @Mob , yes he is, dlFileName is dl directory from file choser and + \\ + filename, it's just print to console with \

Comment: You should use / instead of \. There is never any need to use backslashes in Java filenames.

Comment: @EJP Welcome to windows development, here is you can use / and \\ :), BTW, he can try create file as I wrote below

Comment: Write out the filename you're passing to the File constructor enclosed in quotes. Trimming leading and trailing whitespace from filenames is always a good idea. Perhaps there is a leading / trailing space somewhere that you don't see in the stacktrace.

Comment: Nit picky, but y try using File.seperator rather then using "\\"

Comment: @SergiiZagriichuk I'm fully aware of that, since about 1987 actually. It isn't relevant. There is no *necessity* to use \ in Java filenames. Welcome to the world of Java development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `File targetFile = new File(dlDirectory, filesToRetrieve[i]);`

P.S.
maybe try with `trim()` file name.

Comment: This MIGHT be better suited as a comment until it can verified as working solution, IMHO, HOWEVER, I like it

Comment: Why it is not tried I've tried it on my MAC author can try on his Windows :)

Comment: IMHO It's a great "suggestion"

Comment: File targetFile = new File(dlDirectory, filesToRetrieve[i]); was giving the same error. Using trim() worked. I must have some whitespace after the filename (pulling the filename from an xml doc) Works now, thanks!